# Google Test Framework on Windows check if you are running interactively

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using the google test framework on windows either interactively within Visual studio or non-interactive on a build server. When running interactively I have set the environment variable `GTEST_CATCH_EXCEPTIONS=0` so I land in the debugger in case of an exception on the build server this is set to 1.

Now I wonder how I can figure out weather this is set or not inside a test. This could certainly be done using the Windows API, but I think the google test framework configuration could also be accessed directly somehow, just could not figure so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bool variable `testing::GTEST_FLAG(catch_exceptions)` to determine this.

Comment: I have thought about this, but get a linker error on windows: LNK2001 "bool testing::FLAGS_gtest_catch_exceptions". Guess it's not exported or something.

Comment: @Nils Strange.  The flags are mentioned in the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Running_Test_Programs:_Advanced_Options) and work for me on Windows.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with my build: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977078/lnk2001-with-google-test-on-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Just out of curiosity what platform are you using gtest on?

Comment: @Nils I'm on Windows 7, and use MSVC10 & MSVC11.

Comment: I have MSVC9 and Win 7 as well.

Comment: It is quite strange. With VS 11 I got it working with 09 just having testing::GTEST_FLAG(print_time); on a line works, but not bool asdf = bool asdf = testing::GTEST_FLAG(print_time); Do you happen to still have a copy of 09 on your disk?

Comment: @Nils I'm afraid I don't have a copy of 09.  When you don't assign the value `testing::GTEST_FLAG(print_time)` to `bool asdf`, I think the compiler ignores the line altogether since it has no effect.